# Is there a good free icon collection for windows like moricons.dll?

Tags: windows, icons

Moricons.dll has plenty of icons for crufty old dos apps like Foxpro. Are there any DLL icon collections with a nicer set of images that are also free to use?

**Edit**

I ended up just making my own dll with the icons I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More up to date icons are located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`

After this, you may want to look at creating your own from pictures.... [Here is an online service](http://www.rw-designer.com/online_icon_maker.php) that will do it quickly for you.

Lastly, I have quite a few Icon projects bookmarked, but haven't really looked closely... One that looks promising is [The Tango Desktop Project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project).

Comment: It does have better icons, but doesn't have app icons.